# Change mouse lay-out when logging in to windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, mouse

Every time we log in to a windows account on a computer at work, the mouse layout is changed to a not-so-popular and for us impractical layout. I will not cover the technical details of why this happens and neither can I indulge why we are not able to fix the root cause. (It just is, like some people are forced to work with IE8 because sysadmins...) The point is that every time an employee logs on to a computer, they have to manually go to control panel, select the mouse options, change the mouse layout to the more common "windows aero theme" and apply this change.

[image]

I would like to write a batch script that does this action for me, and I would like to put this batch file in my startup directory so it is performed automatically. Can a batch script do this and if so, where can I find an example of the appropriate commands? You can assume each user had administrator rights.

Another challenge: our computers are thin clients, so when we "log on" all wo do is perform a remote desktop connection to our personal virtual machine on the network. We're not really booting any OS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with pure batch; I'd go for VBScript or JavaScript; perhaps PowerShell could be suitable as well...

Comment: I think only powershell could work (you can still execute it from a batch file unless it's absent or forbidden) because to apply the changes `SystemParametersInfo` call is required. Run `powershell -c "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion"` from a Command Prompt console and tell us the displayed version and whether powershell is acceptable for you at all.

Comment: @wOxxOm Major: 2, Minor: 0, Biuld: -1, Revision: -1